# Where does speed and velocity differ?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, definition, speed

I'm in Junior High and I still have some confusion towards speed and velocity. They sound like the same thing, where some object moves in a given direction, but there is a difference from both topics.

So where does speed and velocity differ from their characteristics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speed is the magnitude of the velocity. It's a scalar quantity, which basically means that it's a "normal" number. Velocity is a vector, which basically means that it has a direction. So if one car is going north at 30 m/s and another is going south at 30 m/s, they have the same speed, but they have different velocities. There are some physical quantities, such as kinetic energy, that depend only on the speed, but others such as momentum depend on the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a vector. It has both an magnitude and a direction. Speed is a scalar. It does not refer to a direction. Speed is the magnitude of velocity.

For example, a car travelling 60 mph in the Northbound lane of a highway has the same speed as a car travelling 60 mph in the Southbound lane. However, if the velocity of the first car is $\vec{v_N}$, and the velocity of the second car is $\vec{v_S}$, then assuming they are travelling in exactly opposite directions,

$$\vec{v_N} = -\vec{v_S}$$

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a speed and a direction, or speed is the magnitude (value) of the velocity   irrespective of its direction.

In physics, they are distinct concepts with precise mathematical definitions. Velocity belongs to a class of objects called vectors, which is commonly called something "with a magnitude and direction", while speed is a scalar: something that has the same value, regardless of how direction is defined.

It may seem like nitpicking, but it comes down to what kinds of (fundamental) geometric objects are possible in 3 dimensional space, particularly with respect to rotating them. A scalar doesn't change when you rotate it, it is the simplest geometric object one can have (so much so, it is said to be "trivial").

The vector is the 1st non-trivial geometric object you will encounter. It rotates in a manner that preserves its magnitude, but changes its direction, which is fairly intuitive. From there, it gets technical.

The reason it matters is that much of fundamental physics can be expressed as relationships between various geometric objects. Moreover, the requirement that physical laws be expressible in this manner, greatly reduces the possibilities, and thus simplifies the relationships physicists seek to uncover.